# Node/Express Async DB Load, how to deal with models

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm now going to load db credentials asynchronously via Secrets Manager which has caused me to re-think how my server and db are initialized. I've got the db initialize working asynchronously however, I'm not sure how to best handle utilizing the models I've defined.

models/index.js:

```
async function initializeDatabase() {
  ...initializes Sequelize, 
fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
      return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
      const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
      db[model.name] = model;
  });
  
  Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
  });

etc
}

// now using a call back
module.exports = function (callback) {
  if (!db.sequelize) {
    initializeDatabase().then(function () {
      callback(db);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      callback(err);
    });
// tried this
  } else {
    callback(db);
  }
};
```

server.js:

```
// seems to work fine
    require('./models')(function (db) {
        console.log(db);
        db.sequelize.sync({ force: false, alter: false }).then(function () {
            port = process.env.SERVER_PORT;
            app.listen(port, function () {
                ....
            });
        }); 
      });
```

Issue
first example of a problem I'm encountering derives from some middleware that loads the User model.

```
const db = require("../models");
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const User = db.user;

exports.getUserAndGroupsWithEmail = async (email) => {
    let user;
    await User.findOne({......
```

Error:

````
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')```
````

And I get it, since I've refactored models/index.js, but I don't see how I can refactor my middleware any controllers etc to load db asynchronously as well. There must be an obvious pattern that I'm missing here right?

&tldr
how are you supposed to asynchronously set up a database connection while synchronously using it throughout an express application???